# Real clustering GMSMapView ios

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, google-maps, realm

As I understood from documentation Real subclussing only from MKMapView. Is it possible to use Realm clustering with GoogleMaps or I should look for some other SDK?

Answer (score 0):

Right now [ABFRealmMapView](https://github.com/bigfish24/ABFRealmMapView) is designed to work with `MKMapView`, but it could be extended to work with Google Maps SDK.

The internal component that actually does the clustering is: [ABFLocationFetchedResultsController](https://github.com/bigfish24/ABFRealmMapView/blob/master/ABFRealmMapView/ABFLocationFetchedResultsController.h). This allows you to create an `ABFLocationFetchRequest` describing the map search and then it will fetch those objects, either with clustering enabled or not. You could copy how the class [ABFRealmMapView](https://github.com/bigfish24/ABFRealmMapView/blob/master/ABFRealmMapView/ABFRealmMapView.m) actually uses `ABFLocationFetchedResultsController` and port this over to a subclass of Google map view.

The import code is in the `refreshMapView` method, which is called automatically (if `autorefresh` is enabled) in response to the map being moved:

```c
- (void)refreshMapView
{
    @synchronized(self) {
        [self.mapQueue cancelAllOperations];

        MKCoordinateRegion currentRegion = self.region;

        ABFLocationFetchRequest *fetchRequest =
        [ABFLocationFetchRequest locationFetchRequestWithEntityName:self.entityName
                                                        inRealm:self.realm
                                                latitudeKeyPath:self.latitudeKeyPath
                                               longitudeKeyPath:self.longitudeKeyPath
                                                      forRegion:currentRegion];

        if (self.basePredicate) {
            NSCompoundPredicate *compPred =
            [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:@[fetchRequest.predicate,self.basePredicate]];

            fetchRequest.predicate = compPred;
        }

        [self.fetchResultsController updateLocationFetchRequest:fetchRequest
                                               titleKeyPath:self.titleKeyPath
                                            subtitleKeyPath:self.subtitleKeyPath];

        typeof(self) __weak weakSelf = self;

        NSBlockOperation *refreshOperation = [[NSBlockOperation alloc] init];

        NSBlockOperation __weak *weakOp = refreshOperation;

        MKMapRect visibleMapRect = self.visibleMapRect;

        ABFZoomLevel currentZoomLevel = ABFZoomLevelForVisibleMapRect(visibleMapRect);

        if (self.clusterAnnotations &&
            currentZoomLevel <= self.maxZoomLevelForClustering) {

            MKZoomScale zoomScale = MKZoomScaleForMapView(self);

            [refreshOperation addExecutionBlock:^{
                if (![weakOp isCancelled]) {
                    [weakSelf.fetchResultsController performClusteringFetchForVisibleMapRect:visibleMapRect
                                                                               zoomScale:zoomScale];

                    [weakSelf addAnnotationsToMapView:weakSelf.fetchResultsController.annotations];

                    [weakSelf registerChangeNotification:weakSelf.autoRefresh];
                }
            }];
        }
        else {
            [refreshOperation addExecutionBlock:^{
                if (![weakOp isCancelled]) {
                    [weakSelf.fetchResultsController performFetch];

                    [weakSelf addAnnotationsToMapView:weakSelf.fetchResultsController.annotations];

                    [weakSelf registerChangeNotification:weakSelf.autoRefresh];
                }
            }];
        }

        [self.mapQueue addOperation:refreshOperation];
    }
}
```